# What does $\exists x\left(L\left(x,x\right)\wedge \forall z\left(L\left(x,z\right)\rightarrow \left(z=x\right)\right)\right)$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I translated "There is someone who loves no one besides himself or herself" as $$\exists x\left(L\left(x,x\right)\wedge \forall z\left(L\left(x,z\right)\rightarrow \left(z=x\right)\right)\right)$$ but the textbook gave $$\exists x \forall y \Bigl(L(x,y) \leftrightarrow (x=y)\Bigr)$$

Where $L(x, y)$ means "$x$ loves $y.$"

**As I understand the first one says**: "There exists a person such that, he loves himself and for all people, if this person loves someone then this someone is himself"

**The second one says**: "There is a person for all people such that this person loves someone if and only if they are both the same(it's himself)"

Now I wonder **are these two formulas equivalent?**

Comment: 1. Thanks for so nicely typing out your two logic formulae (and in your previous Question). Did you use an online mathjax/latex converter to write them? Which? $\quad$ 2. Related discussions over the same exercise: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+%22There+is+someone+who+loves+no+one+besides+himself%22

Comment: Yes, for both of these two questions, I used https://www.symbolab.com/solver/logical-sets-calculator just type interested symbols and copy the formula from the input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. In your first formula, we can move the $\forall z$ outside the parenthesis. And in the context of $\exists x\forall z$, we have that $L(x,x)$ is equivalent to $L(x,y)\leftarrow (x=z)$. Substituting this into your formula, you get $${L(x,z)\leftarrow(x=z)} \land {L(x,z)\rightarrow(x=z)}$$ which is equivalent to $L(x,z)\leftrightarrow(x=z)$.